# Claiming Educational expenses for my spouse - married filing jointly

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, education

My spouse is preparing for the CPA and I am wondering if I can claim her course related expenses while filing 2021 taxes?

Q1. In 2021, there were only exam related and books related expenses. Are these expenses eligibile to claim?

Q2. I paid around 3k for her online courses in 2020 and I forgot to claim that while filing 2020 taxes. If these are eligible, should I amend my 2020 taxes with these? There was also application fees in 2020.

Spouse didn't have any income in 2020 and 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a good practice question for your spouse (taxes are covered in the REG part of the CPA exam).

Generally, education expenses are not deductible. *Qualified* education expenses may lead to credits, but these generally refer to a college tuition, not CPA exam training. [Read here](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/qualified-ed-expenses) about qualifying education expenses.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, she is keeping REG part for the last. She passed FAR and currently preparing for AUD :)